# Remove duplicate values in a range by rows not columns

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate values in columns in a range. For example, I have the following table (yes, looks like a transposed table):

[image]

How to remove the duplicate columns in the range B1:F3? The desired output will be like this one:

[image]

I tried the following piece of code but it's not working:

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$F$3").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo

I get a run-time error: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: .RemoveDuplicates removes duplicates in columns, not duplicated columns. And what you would like to achieve, remove columns with the same heading or remove identical columns?

Comment: Probably easiest to copy & paste transposed to a temporary location then either removeduplicates or advancedfilter then copy & paste transposed back. Neither can work on rows like a sort. btw, your array should be `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` because you are working within columns B:F.

Comment: Do you need to remove complete duplicates? E.g. Remove Peters from your example but leave other Peters with another age/city?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all columns wich have duplicate values in each row, e.g. for Peter, there are 2 columns with exactly the same values in each row, so I want delete one column and keep the other one. If we have a third column for Peter with the same city but different age, then it needs to be kept.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great and prompt help, amazing! For the sake of learning, I will try all the solutions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** after OP's request

and here's my 0.02 cents

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myRange As Range, cell As Range

    Set myRange = Range("$B$1:$F$1")
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In myRange
            .Item(Join(Application.Transpose(cell.Resize(3).Value), "|")) = cell.EntireColumn.Address
        Next
        Intersect(myRange, Range(Join(.items, ","))).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With

    With myRange.Resize(3) 
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        .EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

End Sub
```

it uses a `Dictionary` to collect "unique" columns label as keys and corresponding column index as items

then it hides "unique" columns, deletes visible (i.e. "duplicated") ones and finally makes all remaining (i.e. "unique") columns visible

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possibility to delete the duplicate ranges and not the columns? I'm asking so because I have another table under my table with the duplicates, i.e. removing columns will remove also the data from the table underneath.

Comment: @Jasu, see edited code. if it solves your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: Thanks DisplayName. This works now great as it kept just the unique values in the range. However, the table below was shifted above and it's overlapping with the initial table. Also, the unique values were aligned to the most right columns of the range keeping the first columns empty .

Answer (score 2):

You don't have 6 columns in your range. Column indexes are relative, not column numbers in a sheet.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$F$3").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), _
        Header:=xlNo
```

Besides, from the very beginning with VBA, avoid using ActiveSheet.

Comment: borrowing @Jeeped 's words: _"Can't get this to produce expected results from the OP's sample"_

Answer (score 1):

You could do it fairly easily with a couple of for loops, something like:

```
' number of columns
COL = 7

' for each column
for x = 2 to (COL-1)
    ' check subsequent columns
    for y = x+1 to COL
        'if they are the same delete the second one
        if cells(1,x) = cells(1,y) and cells(2,x) = cells(2,y) and cells(3,x) = cells(3,y) then
            columns(y).delete
        end if
    next y
next x
```

Comment: It should work for separated ones as well, as the "y" loop runs over all remaining columns that haven't been searched yet.

Answer (score 1):

The following will transpose your data then remove duplicates and then paste over your original data without duplicates:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
Lastcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ws.Range("A1:F" & LastRow).Copy
ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws.Range("$A$" & LastRow + 1 & ":$C$" & (LastRow + 1 + Lastcol)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
        Header:=xlYes
ws.Range("$A$" & LastRow + 1 & ":$C$" & (LastRow + 1 + Lastcol)).Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
ws.Range("$A$" & LastRow + 1 & ":$C$" & (LastRow + 1 + Lastcol)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Remove Duplicates by Column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub nmrewq()
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet13")
        With .Range("B1:F3")
            For i = .Columns.Count To 2 Step -1
                If Application.CountIfs(.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, i), .Cells(1, i), _
                                        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, i), .Cells(2, i), _
                                        .Cells(3, 1).Resize(1, i), .Cells(3, i)) > 1 Then
                    .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One more answer won't do harm. This code shall remove not welcomed columns as well.

```
Sub RemoveDupCols()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Set rng = Range("B:F")
    For Each cl In Intersect(rng, ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"))
        Do While TypeName(Range(cl.Offset(, 1), rng.Range("F1")).Find(cl.Value)) <> "Nothing"
           Debug.Print Range(cl.Offset(, 1), rng.Range("F1")).Find(cl.Value).Delete
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't get this to produce expected results from the OP's sample.

Comment: I tried this, I get run-time error: Object required